# Sorting Problem

Tags: php, functions, css, html

I tried to change the Functions.php to this code

```
add_filter( 'terms_clauses', 'wpse247680_terms_clauses', 10, 3 );
    function wpse247680_terms_clauses( $pieces, $taxonomies, $args ) {
        // Bail if we are not looking at the right taxonomy, 'category' in this case.
        if ( ! in_array( 'category', $taxonomies ) ) {
            return $pieces;
        }
    
        // Casts the term name to an integer
        // Idea derrived from similar idea using posts here: https://www.fldtrace.com/custom-post-types-numeric-title-order
        $pieces['orderby'] = 'ORDER BY (t.name+0) ';
    
        return $pieces;
    }
```

And it didn't work, what's wrong? How do I identify where to put the code in functions.php?
It orders them as 1,10,11,12,13...2,21,22,23,24,25. I don't want to add 0 to 1-9 numbers. How can I fix this issue?